# What do I have to fear, after wearing 2 Safe Rings?

Tags: bloodstained-ritual-of-the-night

I just got two Safe Rings because of their heavy defense boosts, even though wearing them both makes my physical attacks nearly useless.

If I just want to run through as many rooms as possible, as safe as possible, I think I'm good.

But what still threatens a Mariam with 45 DEF? I've reached the Warp Mirror at the Garden of Silence, but I haven't been hit by anything with my new build yet. Is there anything near my deepest traversal in the castle that can deal more than 1 HP of damage? Other than bosses, since I presume they're a bit more dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

Well, 45 DEF seems only good to stop things in Arvantville from dealing more than 1 HP of damage. Barbatos of the Garden of Silence deal 11 damage per shot, and then there's the boss right above the Garden of Silence Warp Window-thing, dealing 20 Damage at least, per hit.